# how to write the rule for admin page in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$     index.php?p=$1&id=$2            [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$                     index.php?p=$1                  [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^admin/$                                admin/index.php                 [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^$                                      index.php?p=index               [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

but whenever i type: `http://site-my.com/admin/` i won't  understand that i want to call `index.php` in folder admin.
Could someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your admin rewrite rule ABOVE the regex rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule     ^admin/$                                admin/index.php                 [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$     index.php?p=$1&id=$2            [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$                     index.php?p=$1                  [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^$                                      index.php?p=index               [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

Otherwise your regex (in particular the 2nd one in your original order) eats up admin, and your third rule never gets applied.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have never thought of it. Thought it was some painful thing.